# error C2825: '_Container': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I added priority_queue to my code. When I do, I get this error:

error C2825: '_Container': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

it leads to line 218 of the queue file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\queue

```
#include "node.h"
typedef std::pair<Nodes*, unsigned int> PathDistPair;

struct PairComparator
{
    bool operator()(PathDistPair i, PathDistPair j)
    {
        return i.first > j.first;
    }
};



MinHeap;
typedef std::priority_queue<float, PathDistPair*, PairComparator> MinHeap;
```

in node.h:

```
class Node;
typedef std::vector<Node*> Nodes;


class Node
{
....
```

This is right up there in the "least helpful error messages" award category. I have no idea what to do about this, other than giving up and coming up with my own priority_queue.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [priority queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) typedef doesn't specify a container in which the queue will store its items.

You need to replace your `PathDistPair*` template parameter with a container type holding `PathDistPair*` to tell `priority_queue` the underlying structure you want to use.

```
 // E.g. Using a vector.
 typedef std::priority_queue<float, std::vector<PathDistPair*>, PairComparator> MinHeap;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was required to specify what kind of data structure the priority_queue was to use.